# Find the minimum of a list of dictionaries with respect to a specific key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this :

```
[{'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': '47'},{'prisonniers': [],'sécurité':'92'}, {'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': '38'}]
```

And I need to put inside another list the dict which has the lowest 'sécurity', in this case, I need this:

```
myList = [{'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': '38'}]
```

Comment: Create a function to extract the security value (as number) from one list item and use it as `key` for `min` function over the list.

Comment: I'm certain this must be a duplicate, but I can't find a good dupe target right now. In any case, there are dozens of existing questions on Stack Overflow about manipulating a list of dicts, and about techniques like using the `key` argument of `min`, `max`, and `sorted`.

Comment: For example, there's this highly upvoted question, which covers very similar ground: [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Answer (score 5):

`min` function accepts an argument named `key`, it will find the minimum of an iterable based on `key` that can be callable. so, try this:

```
l = [{'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': '47'},{'prisonniers': [],'sécurité':'92'}, {'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': '38'}]

min(l, key=lambda x:x['sécurité'])
```

the output will be

```
{'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': '38'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [mehrdad-pedramfar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53683090/3620003), but I prefer using [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) from the `operator` module for readability.

Setup:

```
from operator import itemgetter
data = [{'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': '47'},{'prisonniers': [],'sécurité':'92'}, {'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': '38'}]
```

Solution:

```
>>> min(data, key=itemgetter('sécurité'))
{'prisonniers': [], 'sécurité': '38'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min` to do that, setting as key `securite` for finding the minimum value:

```
inList = [{'prisonniers': [], 'securite': '47'},{'prisonniers': [],'securite':'92'}, {'prisonniers': [], 'securite': '38'}]

value = min(inList, key=lambda elem: elem['securite'])
print(value)
```

Output:

```
{'prisonniers': [], 'securite': '38'}
```

In the above example, I replaced `é` with `e` but it will work fine in your case too.

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar sorry, obviously you got it first and me a couple of seconds later.

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar: Just because someone else posted an equivalent answer doesn't mean the answer deserves a downvote. We don't want to upvote the "fastest gun in the West" but rather the *best* answer.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden, thank you for your remark. It just took a little longer to post it than mehrdad-pedramfar.

Comment: @FatihAkman should I find a different name for that variable then?

Comment: Thank's but i have a problem. I have a dictionnary like this one

Comment: @FatihAkman: If you need to clarify your question, edit your question rather than adding more comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:
Step: Find the least "sécurité" using `min([ i['sécurité'] for i in input_list])` then use list comprehension again `print` the matching "sécurité" with minimum value:

```
aa = [print(i) for j in input_list if j['sécurité'] == min([ i['sécurité'] for i in input_list])]
```